# Snapping extension: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clone')

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Our web application is utilizing the Snapping extension just as illustrated in this [blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/snappy-viewer-tools) by Petr Broz. We have created three custom snapping tools and they all seem to work fine. However we notice that the extension is logging thousands of exceptions (on each mouse move event) from our production environment.

We have not been able to reproduce the exception in our development environment...

I can't see from the stack trace whether our custom tools are causing the exceptions or if they derive from Autodesk extensions. Whatever the source is, this seems like an internal error and it would be great if you could have a look at it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clone')
    at y.edgeSnapping (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:11896)
    at y.meshSnapping (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:7061)
    at y.snapping3DtoMesh (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:7644)
    at y.snapping3D (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:4681)
    at y.onMouseMove (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:23212)
    at y.handleMouseMove (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/extensions/Snapping/Snapping.min.js:17:22233)
    at l.__invokeStack (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1091171)
    at l.handleMouseMove (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1093668)
    at HTMLDivElement.mousemove (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.93.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1095126)
    at v.invokeTask (https://"our-domain"/polyfills.js:1:2333)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of places inside the `edgeSnapping` method where we compute a custom `THREE.Vector3` object and clone it using its `clone` method. Can you see which of the calls to this method actually fails?

Also, if you're using `viewer3D.min.js` in production, and `viewer3D.js` in dev, you could try and switch to the minified version in your dev environment as well, to see if there's perhaps any issues related to the minification itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the logs doesn't show which calls to the method that actually fails. I will have a try with the minified version or see if I can improve the logging.